# Удаление символов из текста в определенных div

Tags: jquery

Как можно при помощи jquery удалить все запятые и символы после нее в дивах с классом test?

```
<div class="test">987,65 </div>
<div class="test2">12,345 </div>
<div class="test">12,345</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите что делает each(), text() и за одно работу со строками в JS

Решение по ссылке:
http://jsfiddle.net/2yJbb/2/

Comment: спасибо. то что нужно.